# Use parameter in API platform annotation

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, api-platform.com

I am looking how to add a dynamic variable into an API Platform `@ApiProperty` annotation.
I found that Symfony allows that but it does not seem to work in API Platform annotations.
For example :

```
/**
 * Redirection URL.
 *
 * @Groups({"authorization_code_login_write", "authorization_code_logout_write"})
 * @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *         "openapi_context"={
 *             "type"="string",
 *             "example"="%app.auth.default.redirect%"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 */
protected ?string $redirectionUrl = null;
```

`%app.auth.default.redirect%` is not replaced by the container parameter with the same name.
How should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, I see here only the one way - to create your own attribute in `openapi_context`, let's say `my_redirect_example`.

Smth like this, in example:

```
"openapi_context"={
    "type"="string",
    "my_redirect_example"=true
}
```

Then you need to decorate [like in documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification)

Smth, like that:

```
public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);


    $redirectUrl = .... # your own logic to get this dynamical value

    foreach ($docs['paths'] as $pathName => $path) {
        foreach ($path as $operationName => $operation) {
            if ($operation['my_redirect_example'] ?? false) {
                $docs['paths'][$pathName][$operationName]['example'] = $redirectUrl;
            }
        }
    }

    return $docs;
}
```

It should work. Anyway - it is just an example (I didn't test it), just to understanding how you can handle it.

Sure, you can replace `true` value with your own and use it inside the `if` statement to get it depending on some yours own logic.

Comment: You're right, decorating the `api_platform.swagger.normalizer.documentation` service is the way to go. I've managed to do it using this method, but in my case I had to override the schema, not the paths directly. I'll write on other answer with code below. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is to follow the documentation to decorate the Swagger Open API generator service (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification).

Add your own service :

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
    'App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator':
        decorates: 'api_platform.swagger.normalizer.api_gateway'
        arguments: [ '@App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator.inner' ]
        autoconfigure: false
```

Then create you service class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Swagger;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * Custom Swagger decorator to remove/edit some API documentation information.
 */
final class SwaggerDecorator implements NormalizerInterface
{

    /**
     * Decorated base Swagger normalizer.
     *
     * @var NormalizerInterface
     */
    protected NormalizerInterface $decorated;

    /**
     * SwaggerDecorator constructor.
     *
     * @param NormalizerInterface $decorated
     */
    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        $docs['components']['schemas']['authorization-authorization_code_login_write']['properties']['redirectionUrl']['example'] = 'https://example.com/my-dynamic-redirection';
        $docs['components']['schemas']['authorization:jsonld-authorization_code_login_write']['properties']['redirectionUrl']['example'] = 'https://example.com/my-dynamic-redirection';

        return $docs;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

You'll just have to find which keys to use, browsing the schemas can help on your Swagger UI. In my example, `authorization` is the short name of my API resource entity and `authorization_code_login_write` is the denormalization context value of the operation.

And here you go :

[image]

Of course, the ideal solution will iterate over all schemas and replace found configuration parameters with their real values. Maybe this feature could be done in API Platform itself (Follow issue : https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1711)